# Finding Text in <td>, then conditionally changing text in another <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I'm working with an `asp:Repeater`, and I need some help. In my table, I have a `<td`> that I want to change colors, if and only if, the `<td>` to the right of it contains a certainText.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <div id="myDiv">
                <table id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="class">
                                Row 1
                            </th>
                            <th class="class">
                                Row 2
                            </th>
                            <th class="class">
                                Row 3                               
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="myClass">
                </td>
                <td class="changeMyColor!">
                </td>
        <td class="lookAtMe">
         certainText
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

In this case, I'm wanting to give a background color to  if the  contains "certainText". It's also challenging to me that this has to happen for every item in the repeater.

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/9fbrU/1/) on jsfiddle, but haven't had any luck using it to implement in my solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  //Find <td>'s in your table id="table" which contains text 'certainText'
  $('#table tbody td.lookAtMe:contains(certainText)').each(function() {

    //You said the test was for the <td> to the right of it
    //which means .prev() will return the <td> to the left
    //select that <td> and change its color
    $(this).prev().css({'background-color':'#a90000'});
  });
});
```

Comment: You may want to hide <div id="myDiv"> until the script is complete so the screen doesn't flicker/change on the user on slow pc/connections.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('td').each(function(index) 
  {
    if($(this).text().indexOf("certainText") >= 0 )
    {
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7592/change-the-forecolor-of-an-item-in-a-repeater-based-on-the-s.aspx

you can use a **foreach** on the type of sql adapter you use, and validate a method for invoking **IF**

> dt.NewRow();

, which is in the example and thus validate each field and assign it the color you want

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `DataSource` is but you can alter the code below to do it the ASP.NET way:

**Markup:**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server"                 
           OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
  ................
 <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="myClass" id="td1" runat="server">
            </td>
            <td class="changeMyColor!" id="td2" runat="server">
            </td>
    <td class="lookAtMe">
     <asp:label id="lookAtMe" Text="<%#Eval("LookAtMe")%>" />
    </td>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
  protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
      {
         YourDataObject data = (YourDataObject)e.Item.DataItem;
         HtmlGenericControl td1 = e.Item.FindControl("td1") as HtmlGenericControl;
         HtmlGenericControl td1 = e.Item.FindControl("td2") as HtmlGenericControl;           

         if (data.YourProperty == "CertainText") {                                 
            td1.Attributes.Add("class","whateverClass");
            td2.Attributes.Add("class","whateverClass2");
         }

      }
   }
```